# Width not 100% on Android Mobile

Tags: android, html, css

I just made an website that's working perfect in computers, but in mobiles

```css
.news {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 top:550px;
}

.news-content {
 width:1000px;
 height:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.news-content table {
 table-layout:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
}

.news-content td {
 width:25%;
 max-width:25%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 white-space:pre-line;
 border-left:1px solid black;
 border-right:1px solid black;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.news-content h2 {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.news-content a {
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 color:black;
}

.news-content a:hover {
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
}
```

The picture of the problem

[image]
It has a menu that works perfect the 100%, but he's fixed, and the others I can't put fixed. the footer and the middle is cutting and I can't find out why...

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-image:url("fundo.png");
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-size:100%;
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

.menu {
 width:100%; 
 height:80px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 position:fixed;
 z-index:1000;
}

.menu-content {
 width:1000px; 
 height:80px; 
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center; 
}

.menu ul {
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.menu li {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 position:relative;
 margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.menu a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 display:block;
 font-size:20px;
}

.menu li ul {
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.menu li ul li{
 width:100%;
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 margin:0px;
 background-color:black;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}

.menu li:hover{
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 color:black;
}

.menu ul li:hover > a{
 color:black;
}


.footer {
 position:relative;
 top:1000px;
 height:80px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.footer-content {
 width:1100px; 
 height:80px; 
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}

.footer-content p {
 position:relative;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 opacity:0.4;
 font-family:Lucida Console;
 font-size:50px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 top:20px;
 z-index:10;
}

.footer-content a {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.footer-content img {
 z-index:100;
}

.footer-content p:hover {
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="height:100%" />
<html>
<head>
<title>CCSOL | Sinta a Energia</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo-news.css">

</head>
<body>

 <div class="menu">
 
  <div class="menu-content">
   
   <ul class="dropdown">
    <li style="width:150px; height:30px;"><a href="empresa.html">A Empresa</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="quemsomos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="nossaresponsabilidade.html" style="font-size:14px;">Nossa Responsabilidade</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="width:150px; height:30px;"><a href="ledsolar.html">LED Solar</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="8w.html">8W</a></li>
      <li><a href="12w.html">12W</a></li>
      <li><a href="15w.html">15W</a></li>
      <li><a href="18w.html">18W</a></li>
      <li><a href="20w.html">20W</a></li>
      <li><a href="25w.html">25W</a></li>
      <li><a href="30w.html">30W</a></li>
      <li><a href="40w.html">40W</a></li>
      <li><a href="50w.html">50W</a></li>
      <li><a href="60w.html">60W</a></li>
      <li><a href="70w.html">70W</a></li>
      <li><a href="80w.html">80W</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="CCSOL" style="height:80%;" ></a></li>
    <li style="width:150px; height:30px;"><a href="fotovoltaico.html">Fotovoltaico</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="fvt.html">FVT</a></li>
      <li><a href="vidrovidro.html">Vidro - Vidro</a></li>
      <li><a href="fv.html">FV</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="width:150px; height:30px;"><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
   </ul>

   <a href="index.html"><img src="brasil.png" class="logo" alt="Português" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;"></a>
   <a href="indexen.html"><img src="usa.png" class="logo" alt="English" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:35px;"></a>   

  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="news">
  <div class="news-content">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="news1.html">
     <h2>Noticia 1</h2>
     
     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
     asahsuahdsuadhaudhuofhoahiosajf
     ahudhasuishfuihdaiofhadoiadadsf
     fdfaffsdgsdfsfasdasf
     sdfdfasdfsadasfsdfdfadfas
     fddfafsafdfsdfasdfasfasfsdfdgas
     dsfafasdfdafasfadfdgs
     </a></td>
     <td><a href="news2.html">
     <h2>Noticia 2</h2>
     
     </a></td>
     <td><a href="news3.html">
     <h2>Noticia 3</h2>
     
     </a></td>
     <td><a href="news4.html">
     <h2>Noticia 4</h2>
     
     </a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-content">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ccsoltec/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="face-icon.png" alt="Facebook CCSOL" style="position:relative; float:right; top:10px; right:200px; height:40px;"></a>
  <a href="index.html"><p>Sinta a Energia!</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried to put 100vw, I already tried to put 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`but didn't worked either...

There're 2 css, one for the news, and one that I use for all the other pages that have menu and footer...

Can someone help me out solve this thing?? its killing me not understand why android is bullying me...

Comment: What happened when you put '<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> ' ?

Comment: you also have the footer in % '.footer {  width:100%;}' but have  footer-contents in px  '.footer-content { width:1100px;'}

Comment: it gets even smaller when I put viewport content, about the footer, I use the footer as image and footer content as space for writing, because I didn't wanted the writing space were further than 1100px.

Comment: @mlegg do u think it might have something to do with the background image?? analysing the code, for me it looks like that the width of the website finish where the image is finishing and the rest is just repeated junk, but I can't find how to solve that, I already tried to remove image and put only a background color and nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Do this for responsive background image using cover

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background: url(fundo.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: actually after putting overflow-x, it solved almost all the problems, just one problem its going on, on windows phone the image have white spaces up and down, just stetic, do u know how can I solve that?? thanks alot for the help u're giving XD

Comment: Do you mean the background cover image has white spacing?

Comment: no no, actually I think that the function cover doesn't work on wp mobile, its just the image on normal size in the middle of the website, without stretching or zooming like in the computer or in the android so its basically white space up, image in the middle, white space down, if u still don't understand, let me know, I take a picture so u can see it

Comment: actually the problem is that wp doesn't cover the screen with fixed... do u have any idea how can I make my background image fixed without using background:fixed;?? and I just saw that even with fixed, if I turn my android tablet, my background doesn't follow anymore... man this thing sucks so much, 3 days trying to solve that and nothing...

Comment: I just gave up, I changed no-repeat to repeat-y, it looks bad, but better than not working at all... if u find a solution for my problem, please let me know...